# Removing Backstack Entry in WP7 Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How we can implement back stack entry removal in WP7 Mango app effectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry.aspx) method to remove the most recent journal entry from the back history. However, to pass certification, you must make sure that pressing the back button takes the user back to where they expect to be.